# Python wav how to get volume of frequency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wave

I want to make a music (wav) visualizer in pyton.

I have code for get volume and frequency, but my output is only: ex. 440hz, 30 db.

I want to see (in one time): ex.

100hz, 5db

400hz, 20db

800hz, 30db

1600hz, 20db

4000hz, 2db

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more details to be sure, but I believe that some sort of fft algorithm would be required.

Perhaps try something from [numpy.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) or from [scipy fft implementations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html).

Both of those would need some love to convert amplitude to dB, but it seems possible.

Comment: Thank you for answer, that is it.

Comment: Glad to help.  If that is the answer, then mark it as such.